# Vim load plugins but can't find command

Tags: vim, plugins, markdown

i am trying this plugin to write markdown http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3994, https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown.

My Vim situation:

- previous installed vim-markdown to edit *.md files.
- use pathogen to manage packages.
- i just put instanct-markdown.vim to the ~/.vim/plugin folder.

here are some strange things:

- when i enter vim or MacVim without open a *.md file, command :InstantMarkdownPreview exist. but when i open *.md file, this command can't be found.
- i had see the :scriptnames output, the script already loaded.

i don't know why? anyone can help?

---

Update Jan 21.

i solved this problem by copy vim-markdown's ftdetect to my ftdetect folder and make a small change

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.{md,mdown,mkd,mkdn,markdown,mdwn}   set filetype=mkd
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.{md,mdown,mkd,mkdn,markdown,mdwn}.{des3,des,bf,bfa,aes,idea,cast,rc2,rc4,rc5,desx} set filetype=mkd
```

the small change is just change mkd to instant-markdown, save this filetype file to the ~/.vim/ftdetect/instant-markdown.vim & copy the script instant-markdown.vim to the ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/instant-markdown/instant-markdown.vim and it works.

some little question is :

- i don't know what after/ means?
- i also search vim write plugin guide & got almost nothing. maybe wrong keywords?

---

Update Jan 23

i understand after means slow loading. here is my current solution, i wrapped it into a pathogen package, it seems ok, anything wrong?

```
mac 01-23 16:13:38 instant-markdown $ pwd
/Users/xxx/.vim/bundle/instant-markdown 
mac 01-23 16:07:40
instant-markdown $ tree ./
./
├── ftdetect
│   └── instant-markdown.vim
└── ftplugin
    └── instant-markdown.vim
2 directories, 2 files 
mac 01-23 16:07:42 instant-markdown $ cat ftdetect/instant-markdown.vim 
" markdown filetype file
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.{md,mdown,mkd,mkdn,markdown,mdwn} set    filetype=instant-markdown
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.{md,mdown,mkd,mkdn,markdown,mdwn}.{des3,des,bf,bfa,aes,idea,cast,rc2,rc4,rc5,desx} set filetype=instant-markdown
```

---

Update Jan 26

As ben said, i carefully compare the syntax highlight with/without plugin, it seems i really missed the vim plugin, but if i just copy the script into ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown, when i open a *.md file the command missing.

and i found if i change *.md to *.markdown file the command appear, so the really problem is seems vim don't recognise *.md file as markdown file. so i change all instant-markdown to markdown, put my folder into ~/.vim/bundle, and i got the vim default markdown highlight, am i doing right? ben?

Comment: As the question continues evolving and changing in meaning, I have stopped updating my answer. You should probably move this to a mailing list for Vim, since it has turned into more of a *discussion* than a question-and-answer. I think my answer should still give you enough information to get this working but if you're still confused it's probably time to go to a [mailing list for Vim](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html).

Comment: I had got all the things i need to know, thanks for your continuous help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed the plugin incorrectly. In your defense, the script page is outdated at the time of writing, but the github page has been updated. This plugin is now designed as a filetype plugin. It should load every time you open a markdown file, defining a command *local to the buffer* for that file. When you edit a new file, you get a new buffer. This way the command is only defined for markdown files.

But you installed it as a regular (not filetype-specific) plugin. Therefore, it only loads once, on the empty startup buffer. When you load a new file, that startup buffer–and the command it owns–disappear.

Instead of the *plugin* directory, you put ftplugin files in *ftplugin* or *after/ftplugin*. The file should either be named the same as the filetype it triggers for, or it should be placed in a directory named for the filetype. In this case, the install instructions on github say:

> Copy the after/ftplugin/markdown/instant-markdown.vim file from this
>   repo into your ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown/ (creating directories
>   as necessary), or follow your vim package manager's instructions.

---

**Edit for new parts of question:**

Note how the plugin recommends installing in the *after/ftplugin/markdown* directory. The "after" directory in Vim is used to provide additions or overrides on other plugins of the same type. As its name indicates, scripts in the "after" directory run after scripts in the usual location. So if you have two "markdown" scripts, one in *~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown/script1.vim* and one in *~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown/script2.vim*: script1.vim will run first, and then script2.vim will run. script2.vim can therefore use things defined in script1.vim, or override settings from script1.vim, etc.

Syntax files, ftplugin files, normal plugin files, indent files; all of these can have overrides defined in this way.

Note also the *markdown* directory created inside the ftplugin directory. This is to allow an arbitrary file name, in this case "instant-markdown" to be sourced even though it doesn't match the name of the filetype. I think you want to keep this benefit; if you set filetype to "instant-markdown" your script will run, but none of the normal scripts will run. For example, you will get no syntax highlighting.

When running filetype plugins, Vim will run anything with the same name as the filetype (e.g. "markdown.vim"), it will run anything with the filetype as a prefix (e.g. "markdown_preview.vim"), and it will run anything in a directory named for the filetype (e.g. "markdown/instant-markdown.vim").

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. i have tried: 1. put into .vim/ftplugin .vim/after/plugin -> can't see the command even in the normal mode, script not loaded in the :scriptnames 2."wrap "like a pathogen plugin, put in .vim/bundle, still can't work.

Comment: and i also try to copy some files like ftdetect/ folder in vim-markdown, still can't work, i don't know what after/ ftdetect/ means, also can't see any filetype declare in the instant-markdown.vim files.

Comment: Do you have filetype detection turned on in your .vimrc, or set the filetype manually? There won't be any filetype declaration in your plugin. The plugin does not set filetype, it relies on filetype being set already. So you also need to be editing a markdown file. It looks like the instructions on the plugin site are out of date but the install instructions on github should work. I'll update the answer, they're a bit non-standard.

Comment: i reviewed the ftdetect file & find some problems, now it works. ok, thanks for your kind help. i have updated the question

Comment: I don't think setting filetype to "instant-markdown" is useful. Did you read my updated answer about creating a "markdown" folder in your ftplugin directory?

Comment: i have read your updated answer, it seems that i don't have a plugin called markdown, only have one called "vim-markdown", i wrapped his plugin in to a pathogen package, now it seems ok, anything wrong?

Comment: *You* may not have installed a markdown plugin, but Vim comes standard with a markdown filetype plugin and syntax highlight file. If you change what filetype you are using for this file extension, the standard markdown plugin and the syntax highlighting will no longer apply automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem as well. And my problem goes like this: open markdown file with the name `README.md` is found supporting this functionality and other file `*.md` will response to me error like: `Not an Editor Command InstantMarkdownPreview`. I don't know what's is going wrong.

My current testing platform is my `MacOSX 10.9`.

But luckily I found a way to work around this, you see, for this plugin we can found it both from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3994 and from https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown. But the install instructions are not the same for those two sites.

- For https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown, it said copy into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown/`.
- For http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3994, it said copy into `Download the script into ~/.vim/plugin`, which is a very common method for installing the Vim plugin.

I downloaded the plugin from the last site and copied it into `~/.vim/plugin` and everything started to work.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: thanks for answer, the problem had been solved & i learned a lot :D